create many PDFs in a row Java iTextPDF
I am trying to create many PDFs,
When I only do one there is no problem, it never fails.
But when I put it in a loop there are times it creates, other times 2, other times 5, but some with errors...
I think that is a memory poblem but can´t find qhere is the problem
Tryed to close the DocWriter, but gives me an Exception
I give you the code:
public class ImprimirRecogida {

    Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10);
    private PdfWriter docWriter = null;
    private PdfContentByte cb;
    FileOutputStream fOS;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);//(842,
    public String crearAutodeclaracion(String[] cli, String rutaFirma) {
        try{

            String codigo = cli[0];
            String nombre = cli[1];
            String direccion = cli[2];
            String codPostal = cli[3];
            String poblacion = cli[4];
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
            File ruta = new File("C:\\Informes\\autodeclaraciones\\");


            try{
                String NOMBRE = new String();
                NOMBRE = "AUTODECLARACION_"+codigo+"_"+sdf.format(cal.getTime())+".pdf";
                String str = "C:\\Informes\\autodeclaraciones\\"+NOMBRE;
                fOS = new FileOutputStream(str);
                docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOS);//new FileOutputStream(FILE));//+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf"));
                document.open();
                cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
                document.open();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ruta.getPath()+"\\"+"ISCC.pdf");
                PdfImportedPage page;
                page = docWriter.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
                Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
                document.newPage();
                document.add(instance);

                try{

                    Image firmaCliente = Image.getInstance(rutaFirma);
                    firmaCliente.setAlignment(Image.RIGHT | Image.TEXTWRAP);
                    firmaCliente.scaleAbsolute(80, 45);
                    firmaCliente.setAbsolutePosition(425, 70);
                    document.add(firmaCliente);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    addCB(225, 670 , nombre);
                    addCB(225, 610 , direccion);
                    addCB(225, 590 , codPostal+", "+poblacion);
                    addCB(225, 550 , "ESPAÑA");
                    addCB(225, 530 , " S.A.");
                    addCB(560, 315 , "X");
                    addCB(102, 90 , poblacion+","+ obtenerFechaParaAutodeclaracion());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                document.close();
                fOS.close();
                return ruta.getPath()+"/"+NOMBRE;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }


    private void addCB(float x, float y, String texto)  {
        try {
            if(null == texto) {
                texto = "";
            }
            cb.beginText();
            BaseFont bFRegular;
            bFRegular = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb.setFontAndSize(bFRegular, 12);
            cb.setTextMatrix(x, y);  //(xPos, yPos)
            cb.showText(texto);
            cb.endText();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public  String obtenerFechaParaAutodeclaracion() {
        //15-19,22-26(incluidos)
        try {
            Random rand = new Random();

            // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
            // so add 1 to make it inclusive
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((29 - 15) + 1) + 15;
            StringBuilder sBFechaAutodec = new StringBuilder();
            sBFechaAutodec.append(randomNum);
            sBFechaAutodec.append("/01/");
            sBFechaAutodec.append(UtilsVictor.getCurrentYear4Digits());
            boolean encontrado = false;
            while (!encontrado) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                cal.setTime(sdf.parse(sBFechaAutodec.toString()));
                if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY)){
                    encontrado = true;
                    return sBFechaAutodec.toString();
                } else {
                    encontrado = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
}

And the call to the method:
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
                ImprimirRecogidaRiojana mImprimirRecogidaRiojana = new ImprimirRecogidaRiojana();
                mImprimirRecogidaRiojana.crearAutodeclaracion(new String[] {System.currentTimeMillis()+"","nnnombre","dddirecion","cccodPost","ppppoblacion",""},"C:\\Informes\\autodeclaraciones\\firma.png");
            }


The problem where in the loop of the dates, not in the PDF section...
Feeling st***d lol
public  String obtenerFechaParaAutodeclaracion() {
        //15-19,22-26(incluidos)
        try {
            Random rand = new Random();
boolean encontrado = false;//****line moved*****
            while (!encontrado) {//****line moved*****
            // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
            // so add 1 to make it inclusive
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((29 - 15) + 1) + 15;
            StringBuilder sBFechaAutodec = new StringBuilder();
            sBFechaAutodec.append(randomNum);
            sBFechaAutodec.append("/01/");
            sBFechaAutodec.append(UtilsVictor.getCurrentYear4Digits());
            
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                cal.setTime(sdf.parse(sBFechaAutodec.toString()));
                if ((cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY)){
                    encontrado = true;
                    return sBFechaAutodec.toString();
                } else {
                    encontrado = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

